# Worst page speed score with Gzip enabled

Tags: gzip, pagespeed

In a server with Centos and Litespeed , when i enable gzip in Cpanel, the domains pagespeed score , from 70 drops under 10.
Any idea why ?

Comment: That looks like a question for [webmasters.se]

Comment: Gzip/Brotli should be enabled by default, does the page score tool mention that you have no compression at all?